# retry : I can't use textarea's style about 'text-align:center'

Tags: java, html, jsp

How to align the text on the center?

In the following picture, it is clear that it is not centering properly for multi-line text.

How to resolve this?

[image]

#### My code:

```
<style>
    textarea.f9p3{
    
    border:0px solid #DDDAD5;
    word-break:break-all;
    height:100%;
    font-size:9pt;
    padding:3px;
    overflow:visible;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis
    }
</style>  


<textarea 
class="f9p3" 
name="mon_a" 
id="mon_a_<%=y%>" 
style="text-align:center;width:126px;" ><%=mon_a%></textarea>
```

Comment: I did JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t014uq77/ 
Please tell me how to help you...

I don't understand your wish to be solved

Comment: also create a a fiddle but question not clear : https://jsfiddle.net/mimouni/09xz7tww/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. Please, try to write clearly and specifically what is your actual problem so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. If you are not good in English, take help of a good translator, e.g.: [Google Translator](https://translate.google.com). Good Luck!

Comment: It might be that a hard space `\u00a0` was at that spot. Did you indeed take "\n" as newline? That should work.